# How can I model the join between the leg and the body?

Tags: modeling

I'm modelling a character from a simple draft. I've done legs and now I need to model the "junction between legs and body".

In the screenshot below I got the two legs and the half body, and I thought about creating a "gradual bevel" that will approach 0 as I get far from legs. As the bevel reaches 0, the two body halves can be unified and the body will start.

Can I achieve this with the bevel function? Or do you have another solution for me?

[image]

Comment: Most people model symmetrical objects with a mirror modifier applied so that they only have to do one side. Your approach is unusual.

Comment: I know I just wanted to model the character as much similar as possible to the draft, that's not my problem, in fact I'm just talking about that half, with or without mirror modifier

Comment: How do you expect to apply a bevel?

Comment: I think you're asking about a bevel because you think that is the solution, but a better question would be "How can I model the join between the leg and the body?" or something similar.

Comment: @RayMairlot Exactly, as I said I'm new to this and if there were a better solution I'll hear it. Mine was just a thought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, start with fewer edge loops. Topology of the base mesh should be very rough as there's no need to have any details on this stage. This will ease the process from the several points of view at the same time:

- It will be easier to model as there will be less edge loops to connect / join / bridge;
- Simple mesh is easy to inspect on whether it corresponds the basic forms of intended result;
- Keeping track of quads / tris / Ngons will be easier too.

You will add details with **Subsurf** or **Multires** afterwards, once topology of the base mesh respects the basic flow of the body.
The starting mesh could be a simple cube, which will be extruded to be of an adjacent form.

Second, modifiers should be used once they are given good base mesh to start from. In this case **Bevel** is not needed (probably yet, but I didn't hear of any cases of using Bevel on organic models). What you would like to add is **Mirror** modifier to mirror your mesh and do only half of work as long as it's possible (you might want apply **Mirror** on sculpting stage to avoid mirrored sculpt, but that will be after a while).

In case of modeling character's hip, you could add one edge loop in the middle of extruded cube to be able to create edge flowing on the inner side of legs. This will make things much smoother.

There are shown 5 rough steps of joining legs and body in the example below. Note that at the stage 3 both upper and lower cubes were subdivided with an edge loop by X axis; this allowed to have geometry for further smoothing leg and making it rounded and not blocky.

[image: screenshot of hip's topology]

See example of body mesh from [this thread on polycount](http://polycount.com/discussion/70358/advices-needed-overdone-muscular-character/p2):

[image: screenshot of hip's topology]

See also related post on topic - [Correct approach to hip topology?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1571/correct-approach-to-hip-topology).