# How to bend blocky arm into torso?

Tags: rigging, bezier-curves

How do I bend this arm (block) so it curves into the torso?

I'm using Cycles and I'm not that good with NURBS curves and all that. Is there an easier way?

[image: Screenshot of arm block in object mode]

[image: Screenshot of arm block in edit mode]

Comment: Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to keep the low level minecraft style you could add an edge loop to the body and extrude the arms. You will need to adjust the weight painting like here:

[image]

For smoother animation see also (note my answer on adding a few more loop-cuts in the shoulder region):

[What is the ideal topology for a shoulder joint?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/415/what-is-the-ideal-topology-for-a-shoulder-joint)

Comment: Note that adding some more loopcuts will probably help get the rounding effect that the OP is  looking for.

Comment: @gandalf3 thanks, I emphasized this on the comment to the linked answer.