# How to make character-mesh deform naturally when animating?

Tags: modeling, rigging

I have created a character-model in Blender. After rigging and skinning it, I noticed that it deforms in a undesired way. Everything moves pretty much as expected, but the mesh around joints deforms weirdly(Screenshots below).

Why is this happening? Is it due to a low amount of vertices? What can I do to create smoother deformations that look natural?

Character in T-pose:
[image]

When his arm is rotated downwards. Look at how thin the upper part of his upper arm is:
[image]

Up close:
[image: Up close]

His upper arm is very thin at the shoulder area, but has normal width at his elbows.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/415/what-is-the-ideal-topology-for-a-shoulder-joint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add edge loops on your mesh  at both sides of a bones joint.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> with the mouse cusror on an edge, click to add one (roll middle mouse button for more than 1), slide mouse to place it, click when it's where you want.

[image]

When done, parent your armature again with automatic weight (you'll play with weights later :))

Comment: So it's because of a low resolution?

Comment: yep, especially joints need (at least) 3 loops, 1 for each bone full weight (they'll follow the bone), one in the middle 50% weight each bone that'll deform smoothly

Comment: Bithur I would add the loop further from the base of the arm. this needs to be the shoulder distance. @Naioai Studios this is why we don't use the T-Pose as much any more. :) If you study the shoulder it's about 4-6 inches off the side of the body. Emulate this in your model.

Comment: @Vince Scalia the screenshot is enough for adding a loop for a novice, this is not a tuto about skinning (look global topo). But it's true.

Comment: Sorry, just a little OCD here :-0

Comment: I don't know what OCD is. It was a good comment, thx for adding it. But I won't edit my answer with this info. (as you were talking to me, i think that's what you expected)

Comment: @VinceScalia (in France we say "TOC" for "OCD", I've learned something new :)) people setting up full IK/FK/deform rigs have to be a little crazy imho...