# My mesh twists when I move a bone

Tags: animation, mesh, armature

I made a character and skinned and rigged him, and used automatic weights. When I move the upper bone in arm the mesh gets twisted and weird.

[image: when i move the arm bone this weird thing happens]

Here is the link to download it  [image]

Comment: It seems like you are trying to upload an image, unfortunately, you cannot just drag and drop.  To add it, click edit, then click the image icon, and then drop your image where it says, and follow its instructions.  Keep in mind that an image is not enough to solve a problem, and you should add a description to your question, perhaps noting what is going wrong and describing the image.

Comment: fixed it :D so ashamed :(

Comment: Don't be, everybody makes mistakes somewhere. :)  And either way, now you know!

Comment: Possibly a scaling or rotation problem. Check that both your mesh and armature are 'scale and rotation applied' (use ctrl+A then rotation and scale). Once done reparent your mesh with the armature. If it is not that, please upload your file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ... and another simple reason here is that you have turn the bone too much... so the mesh is twisted and no more...

Comment: as it seeems its not a "scale and rotation problem" so i will go with the fact that i have turned the bone too much. But if thats true how can i make working hands that dont get messed up when i move them much  ?

Comment: Please upload your model via the link given above. Doing so some here could confirm what the problem is and give some advices if needed... and... another possibility is the concerned vertices have the exact same weights for the surrounding bones (but few chances for that normally)

Comment: Didnt know that with the verticles. So if two bones use the same verticles it gets like that ? 
i am uploading it right now to be sure

Comment: If a vertex has the same weight for two connected bones, the vertex may collapse in between

Comment: Ok, I have uploaded it. To me all is ok... simply think how a real bone may move/rotate and respect it for your mesh. And eventually cut it a bit more (an additional edge loop) at the shoulder. Have a look at http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/415/what-is-the-ideal-topology-for-a-shoulder-joint

Comment: Well here's the problem xD i dont know what is edge loop ._. or how to cut it in the shoulder. i will figure that out tho as long as ia have internet

Comment: I added an answer to illustrate (very rapidly) the bone rotation. The main idea is to figure how your own arm may turn around... our skin/flesh is not so different about that

Comment: You may want to have a look to this kind of information https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl#q=3D+topology. But without knowing it you have made a quite good job with your mesh ! so keep on it !

Answer (score 1):

When a real human arm moves up, this is in this way :

[image]

Not in this way :

[image]

I think this is the main problem here.

Comment: okok i get it :D now i will go make a new caracter with balls for shoulders to test if the arms will be more flexible xD thanks a lot. every time i have to post a question in this kind of site i am like wow why are they helping me ? these people are amazing

Comment: @IAmTehPotatoe, maybe because 3D modeling is really cool and sharing what we know is a way to share this cool thing ! And yes you can make balls for articulation for instance in this kind of approach https://fr.pinterest.com/pin/341358846731315353/

Comment: just... wow these are all 3d models ._. i have to catch up with those people xD i have to make my own game :') (i have to stop dreamin)

Comment: @IAmTehPotatoe, no ! Don't stop dreaming or you will too soon become older than you are ! and they are not all 3D models here but they could be (was just to illustrate what you can do with ball articulation approach)

Comment: ILL NEVER BCOME OLD ><